# Emacs highlight specific words when opening

Tags: emacs, elisp

I can use `M-x highlight-phrase` when I am in the editor. But I want to see the phrase ERROR highlighted in red when I open any file that contains that phrase.
I still cannot figure out how to enable this on my init.el file. Any help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I found something like this `(add-hook 'find-file-hook')`, but how do i specify that I want to highlight an specific word

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are existing modes for this sort of thing.

See http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FixmeMode

From the looks of it, the best version is likely to be this:

https://github.com/lewang/fic-mode

Comment: I do not know about lisp, but is there a chance to execute it when opening a file??  
What i mean is skipping M-x step.

Comment: Of course. The commentary at the top of the .el file gives you the details, so refer to that (and if you need to know the name of the major mode hook for the current buffer, you can type `M-: major-mode RET` -- the hook name will simply be that mode name with a `-hook` suffix)

Answer (score 1):

This looks gruesome to me but if you really want it:

```lisp
(add-hook 'find-file-hook (lambda () (highlight-regexp "\\<ERROR\\>")))
```

Comment: I have added that line to my `init.el` file and it is not working. When I open a file that contains ERROR, it is not being highlighted.
Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Try it in the scratch buffer. Copy it here, paste it into the `*scratch*` buffer and run `Evaluate and Print` from the `Lisp-Interaction` menu.